# How implement a random chat feature on Parse?

Tags: objective-c, random, parse-platform, chat

I have built the account backend with Parse but, I have no idea on how to search for and join a random chat with another user.  When I hit the chat button I want it to search and join a chat. What should I be looking at to implement this? Thanks!

EDIT: Nearly there, just can't search/find another user.

```
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)actionChat:(NSString *)groupId
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    ChatView *chatView = [[ChatView alloc] initWith:groupId];
    // chatView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES]; // This JSQMessageViewController
}


- (IBAction)startChat:(id)sender { // The button

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

    [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [query setSkip:arc4random()%2];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!object) {
            NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");

        } else {
            //You now have a random user from your Database, do what you want with it.

                PFUser *user1 = [PFUser currentUser];

                NSString *groupId = StartPrivateChat(user1,object);
                [self actionChat:groupId];

        }
    }];
}




//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NSString* StartPrivateChat(PFUser *user1, PFUser *user2)
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        NSString *id1 = user1.objectId;
        NSString *id2 = user2.objectId;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        NSString *groupId = ([id1 compare:id2] < 0) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", id1, id2] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", id2, id1];
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        NSArray *members = @[user1.objectId, user2.objectId];
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // CreateRecentItem(user1, groupId, members, user2[PF_USER_FULLNAME]);
        // CreateRecentItem(user2, groupId, members, user1[PF_USER_FULLNAME]);
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        return groupId;
    }
```

Comment: Usually clients also come to developer with a question like this. The only difference is, they pay thousands for it.... Moral: We're not here to give you a fully functional application, we're here to help you with a specific problem you've got.

Comment: @LordZsolt I'm not expecting the code to be written for me. Just a point in the right direction on how to implement it e.g. check out X which offers this for chat.

Comment: Have you tried google maybe? There's even a video about it, comes up as 5th or 6th result besides the other 436,000 for "ios Parse chat". Sorry for my rudeness, but you're expected to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and act accordingly BEFORE posting a question.

Comment: @LordZsolt Yes I have, they all about adding and chatting to existing contacts. Not searching and creating a chat with a random user.

Answer (score 1):

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

 [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
 [query setSkip:arc4random()%YOUR_TOTAL_USERS];
 [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!object) {
                NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");

            } else {
                //You now have a random user from your Database, do what you want with it.
            }
        }];
```